# Set Jenkins parameter from external service call

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

Given:

Web service.

The service has endpoint `/info`.

GET returns JSON:

```
{
  "displayName":"Info Service",
  "version":"961-830ae2c9",
  ...
}
```

When Jenkins job is triggered we need to call that `/info`, get the value of the `version` and set it as a parameter VERSION for the build.

I wanna be able to use VERSION as any other Jenkins parameter: `${VERSION}`

Comment: What's stopping you? What does your Jenkinsfile look like?

Comment: @nitind I'm trying to do it with UI.

Comment: @nitind Most likely "Extended Choice Parameter" is the solution.
Trying to figure out how to do it with groovy script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution that worked for me:

1. Make the job parameterized by checking **"This project is parameterized"** checkbox.
2. Add **"Extended Choice Parameter"**
3. Set the parameter as shown below
   [image]

This is the Groovy script from the picture:

```
    def version = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(new URL("https://test.xxxx.com/info")).version
    return [version]
```

Now you can use `${VERSION}`